# I'm looking for a compact style for the whole document

Tags: spacing

I'm writing a summary of Russian grammar, just for myself. But the sections are short, so a large percent of the space is just headings and stuff. I'm looking for a compact style that will give me a better overview of the content. Smaller headings, less space for headings, etc. Smaller margins, so that more content fits on a page, would be nice too, I guess.

I've not got very much experience with LaTeX. Maybe a completely new style is not what I need. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Using `\paragraph` instead of `\section` saves space. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try `geometry` for the page margins and `titlesec` for the section headings etc. `microtype` is not primarily intended to save space but it tends to do so in general (as well as improving the typesetting). I don't know if `microtype` is of any use with Russian, though.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, don't abuse `\paragraph` for visual effects if you mean `\section`. They should be used in your input for logical mark-up: as cfr says you can alter the appearance using `titlesec`.

Answer (score 4):

Savetrees? http://www.ctan.org/pkg/savetrees Seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about this package!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple layout which just uses `geometry`'s `scale` option and `titlesec`'s `compact` option. If you want smaller margins, increase the value `.8` to a higher value. (`1` would be no margins at all; `0` would be nothing but margins.) If you want larger margins, decrease it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
  \geometry{scale=.8}% use 80% of the page - adjust as desired
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \section{A section}
  Only a little text.
  \subsection{A subsection}
  \kant[1]
  \section{Another section}
  \subsection{A subsection}
  A word or two.
  \subsection{Another subsection}
  \kant[2-3]
  \subsection{Yet another subsection}
  Some words for this one.
  \section{Yet another section}
  \subsection{A subsection for this section}
  Some text.
  \subsubsection{A subsubsection}
  With some words.
  \paragraph{A paragraph}
 \kant[4]
\end{document}
```

[image: Compact layout]