# Why is a second displaymath instance a short line?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, formatting, glue

I wanted to change `\belowdisplayshortskip` to move an equation up onto the preceding line, as there is space for it there, I like things compact in my notes.

However, this also moves equations up, namely those with 2, 4 and 5:

[image: rendered MWE:]

So as I understand it, why is it that display-math counts as a short line? how can I achieve the "moving up" without having space underneath? (`\belowdisplayshortskip = 1\baselineskip plus 3.5pt minus 3pt` would remedy the overlaps, but creates unnecessary and unwanted space underneath 2 and 5)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    % \abovedisplayshortskip = 0pt plus 3pt minus 0pt % default
    % \belowdisplayshortskip = 6.5pt plus 3.5pt minus 3pt % default
    \abovedisplayshortskip = -1\baselineskip plus 3pt minus 0pt
    \belowdisplayshortskip = 6.5pt plus 3.5pt minus 3pt
    \lipsum[1]
    A short line,
    \[ \int \mathrm{1 math}\int \]
    \[ \int \mathrm{2 math}\int \]
    \lipsum[1]
    \[ \int \mathrm{3 math}\int \]
    \[ \int \mathrm{4 math}\int \]
    \[ \int \mathrm{5 math}\int \]
   \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you any reason for ,ot typing these equations within a single equation, instead of trying to do complicated things?

Comment: You appear to be badly abusing the `\[ ...\]` machinery, e.g., by setting a negative value for `\abovedisplayshortskip` and by using `\[ ...\]` to typeset consecutive displayed equations. I find it neither surprising nor troubling that the output of such a dubious exercise doesn't "look right". Could you maybe tell us more about your intended use case?

Comment: Should I not use `\[...\]` to write consecutive equations? What would be the alternative? I like my notes to be as compact as possible

Comment: never use consecutive display math environments nor have a blank line before them, in either case you get a spurious empty paragraph (which as you see counts as a short line) but in general if you set the display skips negative you have to expect over-printing

Comment: @Josh, `align` and `gather` come to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need such compact notes, then you must set the glue values above and below display as follows:

```
\abovedisplayshortskip = -1\baselineskip
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayshortskip = 0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
```

Moreover, define the shortcut:

```
\def\nd{\predisplaysize=\hsize}
```

Then you can write:

```
\lipsum[1]

A short line, 
$$ \int \mathrm{1 math}\int $$
$$\nd \int \mathrm{2 math}\int $$
\lipsum[1]
$$ \int \mathrm{3 math}\int $$
$$\nd \int \mathrm{4 math}\int $$
$$\nd \int \mathrm{5 math}\int $$
\lipsum[1]
```

It means that if a next display math follows a previous immediately, then you must use `\nd` inside the next display. It re-assigns the internal value of `\predisplaysize` to the value as if it were the previous paragraph line full.

Of course, you can add some "plus" values to the glues, but "minus" values does not have sense here.

Comment: I see, makes sense, though I'd wished for a more automated solution that doesn't require me to insert `\nd`

Comment: @josh OK, use  `\everydisplay{\ifdim\predisplaysize=-\maxdimen \predisplaysize=\hsize \fi}` in your preamble. Then you need not put any `\nd`.

Comment: yes indeed that works, thank you

Comment: This is a plain TeX solution, and even there, it's not a good idea to use consecutive one-line display coding.  For that, `\eqalign` is provided: `$$\eqalign{<first line>\cr <next line>\cr}$$`

Comment: Maybe `\displaylines` instead `\eqalign` because there is no ask to alignment. But OP needs to put consecutive displays into your document. My answer respects this and shows, how to set the above/below glues properly with respect to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after the `gather` environment (or its non-numbered version `gather*`) from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{gather*}{\useshortskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[47]
    A short line,
\begin{gather*}
  \int \mathrm{1 math}\int \\
     \int \mathrm{2 math}\int
\end{gather*}
    \lipsum[47]
\begin{gather*}
    \int \mathrm{3 math}\int \\
    \int \mathrm{4 math}\int \\
    \int \mathrm{5 math}\int
\end{gather*}
   \lipsum[47]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While yes, that does work, it does not move the gathered part up onto the short line, and it introduces more white-space between 3math and the preceding long paragraph which I can not remove via setting all of the displayskips to 0pt, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385774/

Comment: @josh: I've added a code using `nccmath` and `etoolbox`. Is it more like you want?

Comment: that only lets me choose shortskip _or_ skip, this doesn't use the \predisplaysize, but that is a general issue with the environments from amsmath

Answer (score 1):

If you want compact notes consider using the [**`savetrees`**](https://ctan.org/pkg/savetrees) package

```latex
\usepackage[extreme]{savetrees}
```

or some other alternatives as outlined here [I'm looking for a compact style for the whole document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201528/im-looking-for-a-compact-style-for-the-whole-document). Also, for better math typesetting, look into `aligned` and `gather` from `amsmath`.

## Output

notice the reduction in lines:

[image]

## Code

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[extreme]{savetrees}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[47]
A short line,
\begin{gather*}
\int \mathrm{1 math}\int \\
\int \mathrm{2 math}\int
\end{gather*}
\lipsum[47]
\begin{gather*}
\int \mathrm{3 math}\int \\
\int \mathrm{4 math}\int \\
\int \mathrm{5 math}\int
\end{gather*}
\lipsum[47]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, the `amsmath` environments are preferred, but they ignore the `\predisplaysize`.
`savetrees` seems interesting, but I myself already change a bunch of the mentioned variables, and I don't like the narrower glyphs. But thank you for the package recommendation, I will probably look into changing more variables it changes to my own liking.